# Bootstrap Fixed Navbar Not Sticking to Top in Mobile Browser

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, nav

I'm working on a website and have noticed that the navbar does not work properly in mobile browsers, specifically chrome. This happens when I scroll down quickly: [Fixed navbar bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izqAe.png)

If you cant see the picture, it looks like the navbar has a margin or padding on top, and you can see content above it, in between the navbar and chrome menu.

The html:

```html
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">

        <div class="container-fluid" id="nav">

            <div class="navbar-header">

                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" 
                  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">

                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                </button>

                <a class="navbar-brand navButton" href="#nav">JakeTheDeveloper</a>

            </div>

            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                    <li><a class="navButton" href="#aboutH">About</a></li>
                    <li><a class="navButton" href="#projectsH">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a class="navButton" href="#contactH">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>

                </ul>

            </div>

        </div>

    </nav>
```

What could be causing this? I've tried explicitly setting margin and padding to 0, but that doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: You should only use navbar-default or navbar-inverse, not both. And if theres any css you've added, you should post it as well.

Comment: @vanburen thanks for the tip, and theres no custom css.

Comment: my doubt is something similar my navbar is sticking to top in large screen(PC) but in mobile view it is not sticking to the top